# How many types of planets are there, and how they be created?

Tags: planets, science-in-society

For example gas giants, eye ball planets (with tidal lock), ice rock planets..

The Earth for example has continents because of tectonic plaques etc.. so how are the others formed?

Comment: Voted to close as too broad. there is a [whole branch of science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planetary_science) about this, it can't be reasonably put in Q&A format.

Comment: perhaps you can help me edit? i want to know in a general way how to create planets given their distance to the star and type of star

Comment: So general question will always be too broad, sorry. If you have specific requirements for the world ou are building and can't find what you need, it's another matter, but writing scientifically valid handbook on exoplanets is way too big task for this site.

Comment: Start by reading Stephen L Gillett's *World-Building*: A writer's guide to constructing star systems and life-supporting planets (Writer's Digest Books, 1996). The field of planetary science has moved on since then, but it's a good beginning. Do research on exoplanets for more information. This site regularly has questions about different planets and their stars. Take time to search through earlier questions about planets. It's a big field. Take your time to learn.

Comment: @Mołot There are quite a few books on exoplanets. But you have to dig to find what you want. Now there's too much data, but not quite enough knowledge. Distilling it down takes time.

Comment: You'd do better to ask on the Astronomy site, but I'm pretty sure that the answer's going go be "nobody really knows".  We've only got close-up looks at a couple of dozen planet-like bodies (including the larger moons), and very limited information about several hundred exoplanets - OK, it's currently 3400 and counting: http://exoplanetarchive.ipac.caltech.edu/ - where we maybe know only its orbit and mass.

Comment: @a4android and that's what university is for, if someone is looking for so general knowledge instead of specific answer.

Comment: @Mołot Sure thing. The OP seems to believe we know the answers, when science is still trying to make sense of it all. Funny how before we discovered exoplanets we thought we knew the answers. The reality is so unexpectedly different.

Answer (score 1):

**The answer is: Your question has no single answer**

You are asking about categorization in the first part, then about alledged formation history in the next sentence.

Categorization is not formalized, even the term *planet* is only very losely defined. Take the time to read through https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet you'll find that the definition of planet has undergone several changes with history and is still changing as new discoveries are made.

Likewise, the categorization terms like e.g. tidally locked are not generally mutually exclusive and new categories are introduced as research progresses. Again most of these categories are rather losely defined, if at all.

Formation theories are a field of active research, and are likely to be further refined. For now, we are unable to determine more than the most basic properties of exoplanets; new discoveries are expected in the next few decades when better instruments become available (e.g. new space based telescopes). Even the formation of the solar system is still very much a field of active research.

Neither of the properties you're asking about is easily enumerable.